# Dynamic onetime binding or force to calculate onetime binding one more time

Tags: angularjs

In angular 1.3 there is one time binding `::`
To reduce watchers I want to use it in my directive.

Problem is that in some cases I need normal binding (without `::`).

Do I have to use two different directives for that or there is a solution to use 'dynamic' `::` attribute?
Or maybe there is possibility to force angular to calculate onetime bindings (in that directive) one more time?

My custom directive is something like this:

```
"<span ng-switch=\"::kolumna.typ_pokaz\">" +
            "<span ng-switch-when=\"cena_waluta\" ng-bind=\"model.ngModel|waluta:ngModel.waluta\"></span>" +
            "<span ng-switch-when=\"cena\" waluta-domyslna=\"model.ngModel\"></span>" +
            "<span ng-switch-default ng-bind-html=\"model.ngModel\"></span>" +
"</span>"
```

In most cases `model.ngModel` could be onetime `::model.ngModel`, but not always.

Comment: I know that I can reload whole directive for a while... `<my-directive ng-if="loaded"></my-directive>`, but I'm looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use an "optional" or "dynamic" one-time binding.  It's a bit messy, but totally possible.  Here's an example:

Inside the directive/component:

```
<div ng-init="oneTimeBindingPrefix = oneTimeBinding ? '::' : ''">
    <div ng-bind="{{::oneTimeBindingPrefix}}{{theValue}}"></div>
</div>
```

Using the directive/component:

```
<wt-wish-added-promised-info one-time-binding="false" ...></wt-wish-added-promised-info>
```

[Source](http://www.blog.wishtack.com/single-post/2015/03/02/AngularJS-Performance-ngrepeat-Performance-and-Optional-one-time-binding)

Answer (score 1):

You could have multiple templates - one with bind once and one without - and then supply them to the directive as an attribute.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      templateUrl: function($element, $attrs){
        return $attrs.tmpl;
      }
    };
});
```

And the markup would look like this

```
<my-directive tmpl="/path/to/only-once-template.html></my-directive>
```

and

```
<my-directive tmpl="/path/to/binding-template.html></my-directive>
```

Comment: No if I have both directives on one page.

Comment: Not sure i understand. How does that stop this solution from working?

Comment: Code duplication is my major concern with this answer.